# IP Address validation in Ruby using ipaddress vs resolv

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie to ruby and had encountered a situation to validation IP Address for both IPv4 and IPv6. Based on my little googling and research I have found that ruby provides in-built methods to validate an IP Address.
Method 1:

require "ipaddress"
IPAddress.valid?

Method 2:
require "resolve"

case 
 when Resolv:IPv4:Regex
 else
end.

Both of them worked for me. But I wanted to know if one method is better than the other. Can anyone explain me about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"resolve" is part of the installed set of Ruby libraries while "ipaddress" is a gem you install.

So "resolve" will be around whenever Ruby is installed and possibly has the advantage that as such folks will be more familiar with it. That said, gemcutter shows ipaddress to be very popular even if it hasn't been updated in over 4 years.

If any of this matters, then use "resolve", if it doesn't then either will work.